# Chrome skips contenteditable attribute with insertHtml in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, ckeditor

I use a ckeditor in which I want to insert a non-editable placeholder. According to the [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKeditor_3.x/Users_Guide/NonEditable_Contents) you can set an attribute (`contenteditable="false"`) to the desired element to make it non-editable.

In Firefox this is working fine, the attribute is attached on the `span` but in Chrome the attribute is skipped.

I have a testcase with the following code:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="testeditor"><p>testeditor content</p></textarea>
<button id="addPlaceholder">add placeholder</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('#testeditor').ckeditor();
  $('#addPlaceholder').click(function() {
    var editor = $('#testeditor').ckeditorGet();
    editor.insertHtml('<span class="placeholder" contenteditable="false">placeholder</span>');
  });
});
```

---

### **EDIT**

I made another test to check if the `contenteditable` attributes is attached when inserting an element to the DOM. This works fine in Chrome.

**Javascript**

```
$('body').append('<span contenteditable="false">placeholder</span>');
```

Comment: @david I don't want the user to be able to change the text of the placeholder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer when I googled for an alternative for the `insertHtml` method. It seems that you can use the method `insertElement` also. So I tried and that doesn't skip the `contenteditable` attribute.

**New code:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#testeditor').ckeditor();
  $('#addPlaceholder').click(function() {
    var editor = $('#testeditor').ckeditorGet();
    editor.insertElement( CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<span class="placeholder" contenteditable="false">placeholder</span>' ));
  });
});
```

Comment: Much probably atribute is lost during native HTML insertion (when insertHTML commnad is executed). We implemented our own insertion algorithm in CKEditor 4 (which is now in Beta - http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/) and that should not happen any more (and it isn't as I checked now).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to set the optional mode parameter to "unfiltered_html":

```
$(function() {
  $('#testeditor').ckeditor();
  $('#addPlaceholder').click(function() {
    var editor = $('#testeditor').ckeditorGet();
    editor.insertHtml('<span class="foo">placeholder</span>', "unfiltered_html");
  });
});
```

see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml